# Проблема с кодировкой имени файла при записи файла на сервер

Tags: php

При сохранении файла на сервер, в его имени содержатся символы(см. на изображениях ниже). Имя же файла отправленное в бд отображается правильными символами.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$filedate = date("Y\_m\_d\_H\_i\_s", strtotime($date));
$filename = $_POST['name'].'_'.$filedate.'';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $Dir.'/'.$filename.'.jpg');
/имя файла будет будет искажено, а именно часть имени $_POST['name']
mysqli_query($CONNECT, "INSERT INTO `load` VALUES ('', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[category]', 0, 0, '$_SESSION[USER_NAME]', '$_POST[text]', '$date', '$Active', '$num_img', '$num_file', '$filename')");
/в бд запишется имя, то которое мы и ожидали
```

Имена файлов в базе данных:

[image: Имена файлов в базе данных]

Имена файлов на сервере:

[image: Имена файлов на сервере]

*Менял кодировку страницы на на UTF-8 — не помогло*

Comment: какая кодировка у таблиц?

Comment: @Invision кодировка utf-8

Comment: Возможно решение такое: move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'], $Dir.'/'.iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', $filename).'.jpg'); и тут я понимаю почему нам надо изменить кодировку $filename. Но все же не могу до сих пор понять каким образом mysqli_set_charset($CONNECT, "utf8") меняет кодировку?

Comment: @Invision И возможно, как-то по-умолчанию поставить mysqli_set_charset($CONNECT, "utf8") в настройках бд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй принудительно указать кодировку utf8 следующим образом (после установки соединеня)

```
mysqli_set_charset($CONNECT, "utf8")
```

Comment: Не работает, установил mysqli_set_charset($CONNECT, "utf8"), по прежнему сохраняет с кракозябрами.

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от сервера. Если это windows то скорее всего для названия файла в системе нужно использовать win1251. Но я бы рекомендовал добавить доп поле в базу для фактического названия файла в системе и в системе называл файлы к примеру так `md5(uniqid(null, true))` это позволило бы каждому файлу иметь уникальное имя, а выводил название файла из базы.